# Toggling play/pause on a multiple audio

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of audio that I have created a custom play/pause button,
Each of the audio has a dynamic class assigned to them, for example ... `custom-aud-0`, `custom-aud-1`, `custom-aud-2`, and so on...

My toggle function looks like this..

```
togglePlay(c, index) {
        this.is_playing ? this.pauseMe(c, index) : this.playMe(c, index);
    },
    playMe(c, index) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(c)[0].play();
        this.is_played = index;
        this.is_playing = true;
    },
    pauseMe(c, index) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(c)[0].pause();
        this.is_played = null;
        this.is_playing = false;
    },
```

What I wanted is that, when I play an audio, and play another audio, the previous audio should automatically pause.

But what exactly happens is, when I play another audio, the previous one is still playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pause or stop any already playing audio when starting a new one.

Modify your `playMe` to take this into account:

```
playMe(c, index) {
 if (this.is_playing) {
   this.pauseMe(this.current_c, this.is_played)
 }
 document.getElementsByClassName(c)[0].play();
 this.is_played = index;
 this.is_playing = true;
 this.current_c = c;
}
```

I had to also save current playing class.

A better approach would be to not use `getElementbyClassName` at all and use `ref` to get an array of elements and use that to access the underlaying DOM element.